# trouble using a difference table to find a formula for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I really need some help please. I have been trying to identify the formula for 10,19,46,91,154.
I did the difference table
10,19,46,91,154
9,27,45,63,81
18,18,18,18
but I am having such immense troubles making this into a formula. Thank you!!!

Comment: Okay, so you alredy found the "second difference" term to be constant, 18. That means that if the original sequence is $a_n$ and we set $b_n = a_n - a_{n-1}$, then we know that $b_n - b_{n-1}$ is constant, namely 18. It starts at $9$, as you pointed out, so actually we can conclude
$$
b_n = 9 + 18(n-2)
$$
This is the difference term for $a_n$. Can you continue from here? Can you set up a recurrance relation for $a_n$ now?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to go from there ):
so far I had gotten 9x^2-48x+10
I really want to get this if you could please let me know what I need to read or what video I can watch I would truly appreciate it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out. I got an=an-1+bn-1 =an-1+bn-1+c =an-1+(an-1-an-2)+c but I am not sure how to setup a recurrance relation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with the formalities of linear recurrencies, you can just guess the correct answer. You saw that the second difference is a constant, so an educated guess would be that the general formula for the sequence is of the form
$$
a_n = C_0 + C_1n + C_2 n^2
$$
Now, we know that $a_0 = 10$, $a_1 = 19$ and $a_2 = 46$. We get the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
C_0 & & & = 10\\
C_0 & + C_1 & +C_ 2 & = 19 \\
C_0 & + 2C_1 & +4C_ 2 & = 46\\
\end{cases}
$$
from which we can solve $C_0 =10, C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = 9$. Therefore $a_n$ gets the simple form
$$
a_n = 9n^2 +10
$$
Easy!